# Why my loading text not stand out tho it has bigger z-index than my background image?

Tags: javascript, styles, z-index, opacity, blur

I'm making a blurry loading effect. My background image has a *z-index of -1* and my loading text has *no z-index*. Everything works except my loading text, I can't see it loading and stand out from my background image...
Does anybody know what's wrong? it'd be kind of you to help! Thank you so much!

This is my JS:

```
const loadText = document.querySelector('.loading-text')
const bg = document.querySelector('.bg')

let load = 0

let int = setInterval(blurring, 30)

const scale = (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) => {
    return ((num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
}

function blurring() {
    load++

    if (load > 99) {
        clearInterval(int)
    }



    loadText.innerText = `${load}%`
    loadText.style.opacity = scale(load, 0, 100, 1, 0)
    bg.style.filter = `blur(${scale(load, 0, 100, 30, 0)}px)`

}
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blurry Loading</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="bg">
        <div class="loading-text">
            0%
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg {
    background: url('z.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: -30px;
    width: calc(100vw + 60px);
    height: calc(100vw + 60px);
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(0px)
}

.loading-text {
    padding: 50% 50%;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #fff;
```

Comment: A working demo would be appreciated. Right now it's empty if we want to recreate a minimal version of yours. Please add more lines of code or insert a demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually visible, but very poorly because you're putting blur filter on bg element and everything inside (that includes your loading-text). Just put your loading-text outside.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurring because `loading-text` is inside `bg`. So when the blur effect is applied to `bg` it automatically gets applied to `loading-text` as well. So the loading percentage is being rendered, but it's blurred into the background image and therefore not visible.

One solution is to have two elements within your `bg` element. These elements would not be nested and therefore any style applied to either element would not affect the other element. The first element would show the background image and the second element would show the loading text.

Here is a way to do that using your code, but I've removed anything that isn't necessary to achieve this effect:

```js
      const loadText = document.querySelector('.loading-text')
      const bg = document.querySelector('.bg-image')
      let load = 0
      let int = setInterval(blurring, 30)

      const scale = (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) => {
          return ((num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
      }

      function blurring() {
          load++
          if (load > 99) {
              clearInterval(int)
          }
          loadText.innerText = `${load}%`
          loadText.style.opacity = scale(load, 0, 100, 1, 0)
          bg.style.filter = `blur(${scale(load, 0, 100, 30, 0)}px)`
      }
```

```css
.bg,
.bg-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 190px;  
}

.bg-image {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/FullMoon2010.jpg/200px-FullMoon2010.jpg');
  filter: blur(30px);
}

.loading-text {
  color: #fff;
  font: normal 32px serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <section class="bg">
        <div class="bg-image">              
        </div>
        <div class="loading-text">
            0%
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```